# How get img src-links from WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm using the C# WebBrowser control to navigating to a website which contains several img-nodes and some of the src-links are built by javascript. I wondering how to get the actual src link (after the javascript built the link).

I've tried to get this correct several weeks without luck. Please anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Br, Stephen

Comment: I'm not sure if this is for the correct webbrowser but there is a [html document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: Thanks for the answer:That's correct, but the Document.Body.InnerHtml contains the html inckluding the javascript. I would like to get just the complete src-link.

Comment: Have you found the Links collection of the document?

Comment: Nope, note yet. Looking for just the src link without javascript inside (or links to javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I used Application.DoEvents() då prerender and extracted the src-links in DocumentCompleted, which was wrong. Works better if the complete rendering finish and after that extract the src-links.